# CollectionView takes unexpected height on iOS

Tags: ios, maui

After updating Xamarin.iOS to the latest version, I realized that putting a `CollectionView` into a `StackLayout` with `VerticalOptions = FillAndExpand` would cause it to take endless vertical space and eventually rule out any other control that has been put below on iOS and MacCatalyst.
If I try to remove the `FillAndExpand` option, it will take the expected space but it won't scroll to the end.
How can I achieve the correct behavior keeping the below controls positioning?

Answer (score 2):

The *StackLayout* expansion option `FillAndExpand` [is deprecated in MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.layoutoptions.fillandexpand). This is the case for **all** other `*AndExpand` variants, as well. Popular in Xamarin.Forms, they are not going to work anymore eventually in .NET MAUI and thus should be avoided, if possible.

Also, the `*AndExpand` options never applied to any other layout other than *StackLayout*. They don't have any effect in a *Grid*, *RelativeLayout* or *AbsoluteLayout* in Xamarin.Forms and .NET MAUI.

If you need an item to fill a defined amount of space, you should use a *Grid* and then set the `VerticalOptions="Fill"` instead:

```xml
<Grid
    RowDefinitions="*"
    HeightRequest="300">

    <CollectionView
        Grid.Row="0"
        VerticalOptions="Fill"
        ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" />

</Grid>
```

This will create a *Grid* with a specific height and a single row which takes up all the available space of the *Grid*. The *CollectionView* placed inside the *Grid* will then fill the available space that its parent provides.

***Important:** This also works when the Grid has its `VerticalOptions="Fill"` instead of defining a fixed `HeightRequest`, however, make sure that this then is not contained inside a scrollable view such as a *ScrollView*, because in that case the available space is virtually unlimited.*

Comment: Sorry if I ask, is it something newly introduced?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean, this behavior worked correctly until few days ago on iOS and still works as expected on Android. I must assume that this deprecation (that led to odd behavior when using a `StackLayout`) happened recently.

Comment: It's certainly possible that this changed with a recent update to MAUI. Did you update Visual Studio recently? Regardless, the `*Expand` LayoutOptions are deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore as they will stop working eventually. Since Layouts are implemented separately per platform for performance reasons, they may stop working at different times on the the respective platforms.

Answer (score 0):

For the `CollectionView` to be dimensioned correctly and to prevent it from taking to much vertical space (and eventually rule out all the controls below) on iOS, it needs to be nested into a `Grid` with `VerticalOptions = FillAndExpand`. This will let the `CollectionView` be scrolled to the end and will also allow any other control below to be shown as expected in the `View`.

Comment: According to Microsoft, using `FillAndExpand` doesn't have any effect in layouts other than *StackLayout* and is [deprecated in MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.layoutoptions.fillandexpand). When you place an item inside a *Grid* and you want it to fill the available space, then just use `Fill`.

Comment: All right, by the way despite being deprecated it works as expected in dimensioning the `CollectionView`. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Deprecation doesn't mean that it won't work anymore immediately, but it may stop working eventually, because it may get removed in the future. It's still there for compatibility reasons while people are migrating from Xamarin.Forms to .NET MAUI.

Comment: It isn’t the VerticalOptions that makes Grid work. Its the default Row Height `*`, which takes available height. Don’t need to specify VerticalOptions; that is moot for Grid, when any row has “*” (or equivalently, any row does not specify height).